# Powerset in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I think I have correctly implemented [Powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset) in Clojure.

```
(use '(clojure set))

(defn powerset [input result]
  (if (nil? (first input))
    (concat result #{})
    (set (reduce concat
           (for [x input]
             (let [set-of-x #{x}
                   input-no-x (set (remove set-of-x input))
                   next-result (union result (set (list input set-of-x input-no-x)))]
               (powerset input-no-x next-result)))))))
```

Of course I'm interested in how a library function could make the above a one-liner, but I'm also interested in how the above code could be made more idiomatic.

1. `(if (nil? (first input))` feels wrong.
2. Using the `let` block to replicate imperative calculations. Acceptable?
3. Could I use `->>` to make the following line more readable? `(union result (set (list input set-of-x input-no-x)))`
4. I'm not using `recur` as I got the "recur must be in the tail position" compiler error.

**EDIT** Removed `(loop)` from originally-posted version. - I had erroneously copy-pasted code after I had already commenced attempting to introduce loop/recur (tail recursion). How use loop/recur in this function?

Comment: Feedback from @stevelknievel on twitter: use if-let

Comment: Library that does the job: [`math.combinatorics/subsets`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.clj#L81)

Comment: And it's part of Clojure Contrib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of random comments on your code:

- it doesn't parse correctly, I guess the closed paren right after `loop` bindings is misplaced. I couldn't run it even after fixing that.
- why do you need a second input parameter? I would expect the signature to only have the input set as parameter
- `(if (nil (first input)) then else)` is more idiomatically written (note the inversion of the then-else branches) `(if (seq input) else then)`
- `input-no-x` can be obtained in a simpler way: `(let [input-no-x (disj input x)])`

Comment: Fixed the code - I had copy-pasted a late attempt at introducing `loop` \ `recur` - which didn't work (want to do this). Regarding the second parameter - it's an accumulator for the recursive call, so another improvement is that the function could be overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but see the explanation here for a much simpler way:

http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~amk/foo/csci356/notes/ch1/solutions/recursionSol.html

Code (from https://gist.github.com/796299 )

```
(defn powerset [ls]
  (if (empty? ls) '(())
      (union (powerset (next ls))
        (map #(conj % (first ls)) (powerset (next ls))))))
```

Comment: You should save `(powerset (next ls))` in a variable rather than computing it twice. :)