# Powerset of collection in Clojure

Tags: clojure, set

Similar to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12979/powerset-in-clojure), here's another implementation. Assume the input is already a set.

```
 (defn powerset
       [set] 
       (reduce 
           (fn [xs x] (concat xs (map #(cons x %) xs)))
           [()] 
           set))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a *whole* lot here to comment on. I'll just mention a few things:

- *Technically*, from my quick search of what a powerset is, this function should return sets. That seems petty, but unless it's documented to return a lazy list of lazy lists, users may try to treat the "subsets" as sets (like using them as functions). I'd finish this function off by `map`ping `set` over the list.
- But to do that, you should rename your parameter, as you're shadowing the build-in `set`.
- After doing the above two, it developed quite long lines and became nested. I'd add in some use of `->>`, and put a few of the lines on the next line.

After that, I ended up with:

```
(defn powerset [base-set]
  (->> base-set
       (reduce
         (fn [xs x] 
           (concat xs
                   (map #(cons x %) xs)))
         [()])

       (map set)))
```

Comment: You can construct the sets directly. Replace `#(cons x %)` with `#(conj % x)` and `[()]` with `[#{}]`. Then you don't need the final `(map set)`. This works whatever kind of collection `base-set` is.

Comment: @Thumbnail You're right. I wrote this answer quickly on my phone on a train on the way to get my hair cut. I could have dug further. I think your suggestion merits a new answer.

Comment: No. You take it. It's a detail. But it's still not quite right. If you supply a sequence with repeats, you get some identical subsets. I think the cure is to replace `[()]` with `[(empty base-set)]`. What it produces from a sequence may not be the traditional idea of a powerset, but at least all the elements of the answer are different. Alternatively, you could start with `(set base-set)`, a trivial operation compared with what's to come.